# If $Z\subseteq Y\subseteq X$ and $Z$ is compact in $Y$, then $Z$ is compact in $X$

Tags: general-topology

Let be X a topological space and let be $Z,Y\subseteq X$ such that $Z\subseteq Y$: so if Z is compact in Y then Z is compact in X.

To prove the assertion let be U an open cover of Z in X and we consider the open cover $\mathcal{U}'=\{U\cap Y:U\in\mathcal{U}\}$ of $Z$ in $Y$ -indeed $Z\subseteq\bigcup\mathcal{U}=\bigcup_{U\in\mathcal{U}}U\rightarrow Z=Z\cap Y\subseteq(\bigcup_{U\in\mathcal{U}}U)\cap Y=\bigcup_{U\in\mathcal{U}}(U\cap Y)=\bigcup\mathcal{U}'$- thus there exist $\mathcal{U}''\subseteq\mathcal{U}'$ such that $|\mathcal{U}''|<ℵ_0$ and $Z\subseteq\bigcup\mathcal{U}''$ and so $\mathcal{U'''}=\{U\in\mathcal{U}:U\cap Y\in\mathcal{U}''\}$ is an open and finite cover of Z in X -indeed $|\mathcal{U}'''|=|\mathcal{U}''|<\aleph_0$ and $Z\subseteq\bigcup\mathcal{U}''\subseteq\bigcup\mathcal{U}'''$- and so this prove that $Z$ is compact in $X$.

It is my proof correct? if not, how prove the assertion? could be that if is false?

Could someone help me, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea is good, but the symbology used is too heavy and confusing.

If $\mathcal{U}$ is an open cover of $Z$ by open subsets of $X$, then
$$
\mathcal{U}'=\{U\cap Y:U\in\mathcal{U}\}
$$
is an open cover of $Z$ by open subsets of $Y$.

By assumption, there exist $U_1,U_2,\dots,U_n\in\mathcal{U}$ such that
$$
Z\subseteq(U_1\cap Y)\cup(U_2\cap Y)\cup\dots\cup(U_n\cap Y)
$$
and this clearly implies
$$
Z\subseteq U_1\cup U_2\cup\dots\cup U_n
$$

Comment: Nice answer! Where do you see confusing parts in the OP?

Comment: @manooooh No need to use all that machinery and, most of all, almost no word.