# Closed subspace $F$ of a locally compact space is locally compact

Tags: general-topology

First of all a referece from "Topologia" by Marco Manetti

> A topological space is locally compact if for any its point there exist a compact neighborhood.

So now we prove that "any closed subspace $F$ of a locally compact space $X$ is locally compact".

So let be $F$ a closed subspace of a locally compact space $X$ thus for any $x\in F$ there exist a compact neighborhood $U_x$ in $X$. So $U_x\cap F$ is a neighborhood of $x$ in $F$; then is a closed set in $U_x$ and so $U_x\cap F$ is compact in $U_x$. Since $U_x\cap F\subseteq U_x\subseteq X$ we can say that $U_x\cap F$ is compact in $X$ -read [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3583160/if-z-subseteq-y-subseteq-x-and-z-is-compact-in-y-then-z-is-compact-in)- and since $U_x\cap F\subseteq F\subseteq X$ we can say that $U_x\cap F$ is compact in $F$ -read [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3583096/if-z-subseteq-y-subseteq-x-and-z-is-compact-in-x-then-z-is-compact-in)-

Is my proof correct? Could someone help me, please?

Comment: So, you want to prove that the intersection of a closed set and a compact set is compact...

Comment: I knows this: but unfortunately $U_x\cap F$ is compact in $U_x$ and not in $F$!

Comment: I think you can skip a step: $U_x$ is compact in $X$ and $F$ is closed in $X$, hence $U_x \cap F$ is compact in $X$.  You don't need to bother with showing it's compact in $U_x$ (even though it is).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$U_x\cap F$ is closed in the compact set $U_x$, and therefore it is compact (which is an intrinsic property).

Comment: I knows this: but unfortunately $U_x\cap F$ is compact in $U_x$ and not in $F$!

Comment: Compactness is an intrinsic property: a subspace is compact if and only if the subspace topology is compact, and the subspace topology on $S\subseteq (X,\tau)$ is the same no matter which subset $A$ lies between $S$ and $X$. In short, $S\subseteq A\subseteq (X,\tau)$ implies $\tau_S=(\tau_A)_S$.

Comment: Well $U_x\cap F$ is a compact subspace of $U_x$ and we have $U_x\cap F\subseteq U_x$ and so $\tau_{{}_{U_x\cap F}}=(\tau_{{}_{U_x}})_{{}_{U_x\cap F}}$; anyway we also have $U_x\cap F\subseteq F$ and so $(\tau_{{}_{U_x\cap F}}=(\tau_{{}_F})_{{}_{U_x\cap F}}$: so it is $(\tau_{{}_{U_x}})_{{}_{U_x\cap F}}=(\tau_{U_x\cap F}=(\tau_{{}_F})_{{}_{U_x\cap F}}$ and so $U_x\cap F$ is compact in $F$. 
Is that what you mean?

Comment: That seems ok.${}$

Comment: Okay. Anyway it seems I found an onother way to prove the assertion and so I edited the question: can you reread it, please?

Comment: That seems more of the same.

Comment: Okay. Thus is correct what I proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3583160/if-z-subseteq-y-subseteq-x-and-z-is-compact-in-y-then-z-is-compact-in)?